# How to create a double link?

Tags: html

If the user clicks the link, then I would like to open a page in a new tab, and jump to `#section` on the parent site. How is it possible without JS?

This doesn't work:
`html
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank"><a href="#section">link</a></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you have to use JavaScript to request multiple URLs via the same anchor.

```
<a href="#section" id="doubleLink">Some Text</a>
```

With JavaScript, you would be able to watch for the onclick event to open a new window, like so:

```
document.getElementById("doubleLink").onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://www.someothersite.com/");
}
```

Comment: I believe that by the "parent site", he meant his own site, not yoursite.com

Comment: I mean I would like to open for example google in a new tab, and jump to a section on my site too

Comment: @friction AFAIK you'll have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `#section` to the address.

```
<a href="http://target_site#section">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use javascript, but not much:

`document.getElementById('myLinkId').addEventListener('click', function() {window.location = '#section'}, false);`

EDIT: As far as I know, it can't be done without javascript. What would happen to a double link that didn't open a new tab?

I realize you may also need it to work in older IE.

```
var doubleLink = document.getElementById('myLinkId');

if (window.addEventListener) {
doubleLink.addEventListener('click', function() {window.location = '#section'}, false);
} else {
doubleLink.attachEvent('onclick', function() {window.location = '#section'});
}
```